# Blurring Non-Uniform Areas

Tags: image-processing, filters, blur

I have an image with arbitrary area (the boundary is shown in gray):

[image]

**I would like to blur just the image within boundaries.**

Ordinary blur causes the background proliferating to image and vice versa. This results in dark areas near boundaries of the image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution would be to create a binary (0/255) mask of the area you want to blur. Then blur the source image BITWISE AND mask, blur the mask with the same filter and divide them. As pseudocode:

```
(filter(source & mask) / filter(mask)) & mask
```

Comment: Thanks. This is equivalent to blurring both image layer and alpha mask layer, right?

Comment: I see it as a filter that only averages over the area inside the mask. But yes, you can also see it as blurring a premultilpied alpha image, then convert back to normal RGBA.